# How can I render a Swagger file (OpenAPI Spec) on a SharePoint page

Tags: json

Does anyone know how to render Swagger files (now known as OpenAPI Specs) on SharePoint?

If I have a REST API that our internal business groups want to use then it seems to make sense to render it on our SharePoint site.

Swaggers generally render in a few ways:
(1) By a hosting agent on the same server hosting the REST APIs represented in the Swagger file.
(2) On a Developer Portal using a rendering engine.

Drupal for instance uses SmartDocs.  I'm curious if anyone has developed a module for  hosting a Swagger/OAS file (json or yaml) on a SharePoint page?  **This does not mean displaying the raw file... it means using the json/yaml to render a page that allows the user to interact with the REST API described in the json/yaml file**.